# Exception handling for user input outside of normal interaction

Tags: c#, html, validation, exception

Edit: I think my question's rambled on a bit, possibly detracting from the point. So, as concisely as possible: Should I be concerned with avoiding exceptions caused by users who fiddle with their HTML request?

I'm using a drop-down field in HTML which is backed by an integer value. This value gets parsed in the back office. Currently, if the integer parsing fails, the site gives a generic error (due to top-level exception handling) and places an entry into the audit trail containing the integer parse error.

Normally, I wouldn't want an un-handled exception to be thrown by bad user input, but in this case the bad input can only be produced by a bot or a clever user. In either of these cases, the error message will not be unexpected, and should not be a security concern.

Is there any compelling reason to handle the exception? If I do this, I'll need to formalise what I want to happen when the user commits this crime. Do I show bots and malicious users their own little validation error? Do I default their values and allow the form to submit?

Comment: Are you using client-side validation and hoping that it won't ever break?

Comment: No, there's no standard client-side validation on this project. Everything is validated server-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I have: It depends.

For example, if you're writing a bank account management system and find out that user is trying to move "Lorem ipsum" U.S. dollars from one of his accunts to another, then that is probably very bad and you should not let this operation happen. User message of a generic error would be fine.

On the other hand, if you are writing a "reverse polish notation online calculator" and encounter a ";" character, you can show the exact reason to the user.

If you are validating user's age, hope it is an integer between 0 and 100, but you get a 2,147,483,647 value, then it should be fine to simply substitute it by 10.

This is more like a *project-dependent* question rather than a *technology-dependent*.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I'm intentionally less concerned with how critical an error is and more concerned with where the right place is to handle it (in my case, either at top-level exception handling or inside the actual web method with defaulting or validation.)

Comment: I thought the answer covers that too, but I was wrong. From my expirience I'd say that the closer error is handled, the easier it'll be to find it. But if you **really** suppose this error will not show up with regular user, I'd stay up with high-level handling. It's hard to tell you something less general without knowing what kind of project you are working on.

Comment: I disagree. I think the closer the exception is THROWN to the problem, the better. A handled exception will never be noticed by a developer or an administrator unless a user complains about the behaviour of the application (sadly, few of them even do this!) That's one reason I'm trying to avoid handling exceptions that I shouldn't, they end up creating common-law features somewhere near by.

Comment: I've accepted your answer but this acceptance includes your last comment (saying not to handle it.) After thinking about it for a day, this is the conclusion I came up with on my own. To answer your question, this is a public facing website taking on-line payments